# powershell: List members of a group in an OU through filtering

Tags: powershell-2.0

My first post here although this site has been a valuable resource for some time now.

I'm trying to have a list of users who are not part of a group with a search base being an OU.

I tried this command:

```
Get-ADUser -server SERVER01 -filter {memberof -ne gg_group_I_need_to_search} -SearchBase "OU=ou1,OU=ou2,DC=1,DC=2,DC=3,DC=com"
```

the -server argument is there because I need to query another domain. this command returns an error, but I cannot seem to find the error in the syntax.

What am I missing?

Comment: add in your question the error.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the interest.
so the syntax is:
    get-aduser -server [domain name] -filter {memberof -ne [FQDN of the group]} -searchbase [FQDN of the OU I want to query]

the error I get is:
Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: 'memberof -ne group_name ' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '14'.
At line:1 char:11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an example of a working filter (IMO...but I can't test it now):

```
-Filter "-not (memberOf -eq 'CN=MyGroupToSearch,CN=Users,DC=int,DC=contoso,DC=com')"
```

The group must be in a `DN` form.

Comment: Nice one! This worked fine! So the syntax must have been wrong.

Grazie per la risposta C.B!

Comment: @knuckle_sandwich Prego, è un piacere essere di aiuto! :)

Comment: So to close this discussion and for future reference:
To retrive accounts not memeber of a group from an OU:
Get-ADUser -server SERVER01 -filter "-not (memberOf -eq 'CN=MyGroupToSearch,CN=Users,DC=int,DC=contoso,DC=com')" -searchbase [FQDN of the OU]